# How can I find the number of the shortest paths between two points on a 3D lattice grid?

Tags: combinatorics

A similar question has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103470/how-can-i-find-the-number-of-the-shortest-paths-between-two-points-on-a-2d-latti)  , but what if we want to find the shortest path between two points in a 3d-space?

Of course we are jut allowed to move along the lattice.

Comment: You should make it explicit that you want steps along the lattice.  Otherwise, there is one shortest path, the straight segment.

Comment: of course... thank you.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think multinomials solve your question.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you’re talking about lattice paths, say from $\langle 0,0,0\rangle$ to $\langle k,m,n\rangle$ for some non-negative integers $k,m,n$, you want the [multinomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients)

$$\binom{k+m+n}{k,m,n}=\frac{(k+m+n)!}{k!m!n!}\;.$$

You must take a total of $k+m+n$ steps, $k$ of them in the positive $x$-direction, $m$ of them in the positive $y$-direction, and $n$ of them in the positive $z$-direction. There are $\binom{k+m+n}k$ ways to choose when to take the steps in the $x$-direction, and there are then $\binom{m+n}m$ ways to choose which of the remaining $m+n$ steps are to be in the $y$-direction. Finally,

$$\binom{k+m+n}k\binom{m+n}m=\frac{(k+m+n)!}{k!m!n!}\;.$$

Comment: Generally, the answer in n dimension is $$\sum_{i=1}^nk_i\choose k_1,...,k_n$$ then?

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you!

Comment: @powermetal114: You’re welcome!

Comment: @CBenni: Yes, that’s right.