# Given a lattice path, how do you define it as a subset of some larger set?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

So it's clear that the total number of shortest routes in a lattice path given a $mxn$ grid is $\binom{s}{r}$ where $s$ is the total number of steps, and $r$ is the total number of right steps. But this is simply to easy. So consider instead this question.

Given a shortest path $p$, how does this determine some $r$-element subset of an $s$-element set $A_p$?

Note: Edited for clarification.

Comment: @mjqxxxx I edited it. Forgot to introduce what $r$ & $s$ were. Maybe that provides a little clarification? I'm completely lost though.

Comment: Hm... The way I know that the number of lattice paths is ${s \choose r}$ makes explicit use of the fact that it's an $r$-element subset of a particular set. How did you come across that formula?

Comment: @EricStucky don't know if this helps, but the $s$ and $r$ are really only making things more complicated. $r$ in this case could be either $m$ or $n$, and $s=m+n$.

Comment: That might help, but it doesn't answer the question: how do you know that ${s \choose r}$, or ${m+n \choose n}$ if you prefer, is the number of lattice paths?

Comment: @EricStucky It's because of binomial coefficients, which is proved [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321192/lattice-paths-and-catalan-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

The linked [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321192/lattice-paths-and-catalan-numbers) from the comments explains what the set and the subset are:

> The reason is quite simple: you must make a total of $m+n$ moves, consisting of $m$ moves down and $n$ to the right, in any order, and there are $\binom{m+n}m$ ways to choose which of the $m+n$ moves are down (or, equivalently, $\binom{m+n}n$ ways to choose which $n$ of them are to the right).

If you want to use an arbitrary subset $A$, rather than the subset of moves, this is also allowed, you just need a bijection $f$ between that set and the set of moves, then any path corresponds to a $n$-element subset, where $a\in A$ is in the subset iff $f(a)$ moves right.